# How I could remove random generated lines and dots from this image? [Pre-OCR with Tesseract]

Tags: c#, opencv, tesseract

I'm trying to solve captchas by OCR them with Tesseract on C#. I'm grabbing the captcha with Selenium and I apply some effects to clean the image, and I end up with this that is not clean enough to read properly.

I'm asking here if someone could help me write an OpenCV code that could remove the lines and dots as they have different widths.

Image:

[image]

Image after OpenCv changes:

[image]

```
var image = Resize(img, 800, 600);
            image.Save("captcha.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            Mat imageIn = Cv2.ImRead("captcha.png", ImreadModes.Grayscale);
            Mat edges = new Mat();

            Cv2.Canny(imageIn, edges, 100, 100);

            edges.SaveImage("captcha1.png");
```

Anyway to improve it a bit more? Tesseract doesn't recognize it yet.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know how to do it in C#, but in python, this code works

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("Md5XC6G.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow("original", img)

img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)

kernel = np.ones((14, 14), np.uint8)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
newkernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
inv = cv2.erode(close, newkernel, iterations=1)

inv = cv2.bitwise_not(inv)

cv2.imshow("inverted", inv)
cv2.imwrite("inverted.jpg", inv)

custom_config = r'-l eng --oem 3 --psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(inv, config=custom_config)
print("Detected captcha is:", text)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result when run

```
Detected captcha is: wjr4s2
```

Comment: You're a beast, ill try to translate it and I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi again @us2018, code sometimes works with some captchas, but with some that got lines between the letters cannot extract the text. Any way to improve it a little bit? Here you have another image to try with: https://imgur.com/a/UUjFgOz Thanks a lot!